# Почему не могу отправить письмо в html формате

Tags: php

```
<?php

 /////////////////////////////////////
 // Почтовая рассылка v2.3          //
 // (C) 2006-2008 Яницкий Александр //
 // Веб сайт: janicky.com           //
 // e-mail: support@janicky.com     //
 // icq: 305-972                    //
 /////////////////////////////////////

// Уровень обработки ошибок
   Error_Reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

// Подключаем вспомогательные библиотеки
   require_once "admin/lib/connect.inc.php";
   require "admin/lib/functions.inc.php";

// Настройки
   $query = "SELECT * FROM ".DB_SETTING."";  
   $result = mysql_query($query);
   $settings = mysql_fetch_array($result);

// Проверяем правильность заполнения полей
   if(empty($_POST['name'])) error("Отсутствует имя!");
   if(empty($_POST['email'])) error("Не введён e-mail!");

// Удаляем теги и пробелы с краев
   $_POST['name'] = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
   $_POST['email'] = strtolower(trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email'])));

// Проверяем правильность ввода e-mail
   if(!preg_match("/^[-0-9a-z_\.]+@[-0-9a-z_]+\.(?:com|edu|gov|int|mil|net|org|biz|info|museum|coop|name|aero|mobi|[a-z][a-z])$/i", $_POST['email'])) error("Введите e-mail в виде <i>name@mail.ru</i>");

   $ip = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");
   $cod = getRandomCod();

// Проверяем не имеется ли уже такой e-mail в базе данных
   $query = "SELECT * FROM ".DB_USERS." WHERE email LIKE '".$_POST['email']."'";
   $result = mysql_query($query);

   if(!$result) error("Ошибка при обращении к базе данных!");

   if($result)
   {
      if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0) error("Подписка на данный e-mail уже произведена!");
   }

// Заменяем одинарные кавычки обратными
   $_POST['name'] = str_replace("'", "`", $_POST['name']);
   $_POST['email'] = str_replace("'", "`", $_POST['email']);

// Добавляем подписчика в таблицу users
   $query = "INSERT INTO ".DB_USERS." VALUES (0,
                                             '".$_POST['name']."',
                                             '".$_POST['email']."',
                                             '$ip',
                                             '$cod',
                                             NOW(),
                                             'noactive',
                                             '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
                                             '0')";
   if(mysql_query($query))
   {
      $id = mysql_insert_id();

   // Генерим тело письма
      $subject = "Подписка на расcылку wor(l)d $HTTP_HOST";

      if($settings['del'] == "yes") $mes = "У Вас ".$settings['day']." дн. чтобы активировать подписку.";

 $message = "Здравствуйте, ".$_POST['name']."!\n\n";
      $message .= "Получение рассылки возможно после завершения этапа активации подписки. $mes Для этого следует перейти по следующей ссылке: http://".$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].root()."add.php?status=active&id=$id&key=$cod\n\n";

$header="From: robot@worldgmn.ru\nReply-To:  robot@worldgmn.ru"; 
$header.="\nContent-type: text/html; charset=\"windows-1251\""; 
$text="<HTML>\r\n";
$text.="<HEAD>\r\n";
$text.="<META http-equiv=Content-Type content='text/html; charset=windows-1251'>\r\n";
$text.="</HEAD>\r\n";
$text.="<BODY>\r\n";
$text.="<h1>Письмо в HTML-формате</h1>\r\n";
$text.="<p>Это обычный абзац (в отличие от предыдущего заголовка 1-го уровня).\r\n";
$text.="</BODY>\r\n";
$text.="</HTML>";
$maeeage. =" http://maps.do.am/\n\n";
      $message .= "Если Вы не производили подписку на данный адрес, просто проигноруйте данное письмо или перейдите по ссылке: http://".$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].root()."delete.php?id=$id&key=$cod\n\n";
      $message .= "С уважением, администратор сайта $HTTP_HOST\r\n";

      if($settings[codirovka] == 1)
      { 
         $charset = "windows-1251";

         if(check_rus($subject) == true)
         {
            $subject = base64_encode($subject);  
            $subject = "=?$charset?B?$subject?=";
         }
      }
      else if($settings[codirovka] == 2)
      {
         $charset = "koi8-r";
         $message = convert_cyr_string($message,'w','k');

         if(check_rus($subject) == true)
         {
            $subject = convert_cyr_string($subject,'w','k');
            $subject = base64_encode($subject);  
            $subject = "=?$charset?B?$subject?=";
         }
         else
         {
            $subject = convert_cyr_string($subject,'w','k');
         }
      }
      else
      {
         $charset = "utf-8"; 
         $message = iconv('windows-1251','utf-8',$message);

         if(check_rus($subject) == true)
         {
            $subject = iconv('windows-1251','utf-8',$subject);
            $subject = base64_encode($subject);  
            $subject = "=?$charset?B?$subject?=";
         }
         else
         {
            $subject = iconv('windows-1251','utf-8',$subject);
         }
      }

      $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";

      if($settings['ShowAdmin'] == "yes") { $headers .= "From: $HTTP_HOST <".$settings['admin_email'].">\n"; }
      else { $headers .= "From: $HTTP_HOST <robot@$HTTP_HOST>\n"; }

      $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=$charset\n";
      $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n";
      $headers .= "X-Mailer: PostSender\r\n";

      if(@mail($_POST['email'], $subject, $message, $headers))
      {
         echo "<HTML><HEAD>\n";
         echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' CONTENT='3; URL=".$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]."'>\n";
         echo "</HEAD><BODY><center>Сейчас на ваш e-mail будет выслано письмо, по указанной в нём ссылке можно будет активировать подписку.!</center></BODY></HTML>\n";
      }
   }
   else
   {
      error("Ошибка при выполнение SQL запроса!");    
   }

?>
```

Comment: вот даже читать не хочется =\

уберите лишний код, а то что останется отформатируйте с помощью кнопки 101010

Comment: В строке 85 ошибка `$maeeage. =" http://maps.do.am/\n\n";` Пробел между точкой и равно!

З.Ы. Даже отредактировать этот ГК не смог, редирект в тему через 3 сек. какойто =(

Comment: LOL действительно redirect :D

     <META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' CONTENT='3; URL=".$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]."'>

Пичаль :D

Comment: ага досмотрел)))

Comment: $maeeage. =" http://maps.do.am/\n\n";
вот ето ты не смотри ето я снимаю он опять не понимает html

Comment: С хрома что ли оба?)

ЗЫ: хедеры разделяются **`\r\n`**, а не **`\n`**

Comment: я да, тем не менее считаю что то, что такое происходит абсолютным бредом =)

Comment: Я с оперы!

Answer (score 2):

> > `$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=$charset\n";`

Удалите эту строку. Выше определяется как

```
$header.="\nContent-type: text/html; charset=\"windows-1251\"";
```